# Google Analytics - Audience Data Missing after 6:00am

Tags: google-analytics

Did the Google Analytics Audience stats go offline today? My website is showing no usage after 6:00am today.

[image: Usage Drop]

If I swap to the "real time" panel though I can see usage being recorded.

[image: real time usage]

I've checked the app status page on Google as well and it says there are no known issues with the Analytics.

[image: app status]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics reports, other than Realtime, populate on a delay of up to 48 hours (I have never seen anything take 48 hours, but that's the official Data Processing Latency time in the [Data Limits documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)). Generally you can expect reports to have data through the previous day but rely only on Realtime for the current day.